How to handle events of a parent control inside a derived control in C++/CLI
I'm implementing MyUserControl in C++/CLI derived from Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::UserControl to handle C# - Win32 glue logic for libs written in native logic, and would like to handle the events like SizeChanged from the parent inside the derived control itself. The problem is that I can't find the correct syntax to attach my class handler to the parent event. Here is the first attempt handler in the derived class.
void OnSizeChanged( System::Object^ sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::SizeChangedEventArgs^ args) override
{
    /* do resize MyUserControl from inherited properties */
    UpdateWindowLayout( this>ActualWidth, this->ActualHeight);
}

The problem with the code above is that OnSizeChanged(), if exists, is never called and probably already consumed by the ancestor Control.
The next approach is to manually wire the event in the class constructor as follows:
static void OnSizeChanged( System::Object^ sender, Microsoft::UI::Xaml::SizeChangedEventArgs^ args) 
{
    /* do resize on Sender */
}

and in the construcor add:
MyUserControl()
{
    this->SizeChanged += gcnew EventHandler(this, MyUserControl::OnSizeChanged);
}

but the += syntax that I have seen in several examples here is not correct in this case. What am I doing wrong?
The brute force approach that works is to register the event in C# and send it back to MyUserControl.
private void MyUserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null && sender is MyUserControl)
    {
       var view = sender as MyUserControl;
       view.OnSizeChanged(sender, e);
    }
}
    
private void AttachMyUserControl(Border border)
{
   var myuc = new MyUserControl();
   border.Child = myuc;
   myuc.SizeChanged += MyUserControl_SizeChanged;
}

The code above is ugly to say the least, but works.

Why don't you use C++/WinRT instead of C++/CLI which has an incertain present and future.

Thanks Simon. here is why, C++/CLI allows you to define managed clases and interfaces like this "public ref class MyWinUI3UserControl : UserControl {}" that can be consumed by C# and other managed languages. Can you do that with WinRT?, if yes I'll appreciate son links pointing me in the right directon.

C++/WinRT doesn't allow you to write .NET code, but it does allow you to write WinRT components (for WinUI3 or other) that you can use from .NET (or any WinRT projected language)

... allow you to write WinRT components ...
I need to research on that.
